# About infinite languages in RE and coRE

Tags: complexity-theory, formal-languages

Let $L \in RE$. Then $L$ might be finite or infinite.

I assume this is also true for $coRE$.

But, if I have a language $L \notin RE$, it necessarily means that $L$ is infinite, am I correct?

Also, if $L \notin coRE$ then $L$ is infinite, right?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Right. All finite languages are decidable.

Comment: @EvangelosBampas Thank you! :)